# X-shaped crossword

Tags: crosswords

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>   1. Having very bad taste
>   4. English elite school
>   8. Shiraz's country
>   9. Russian car
>   10. Body part or storage device
>   12. "Pas" in *faux pas*
>   13. Mall customer
>   15. Baseballer Gehrig
>   16. Following as a consequence
>   21. Diseases, for example
>   23. A type of golf club
>   24. Frozen beverage
>   25. Actor Ayres and others
>   26. A common last name in Pakistan
>
> **Down**
>   1. Accompanying dish
>   2. A part of the eye
>   3. Line-walking musician
>   5. London art gallery
>   6. East Germany's border river
>   7. California wine region
>   11. Structural elements that can be Ionic or Doric, for example
>   12. A famous piece of Soviet technology
>   14. A European or a piece of track and field equipment
>   16. Train transport
>   17. A country name on euro coins
>   18. How to take it on Kokomo
>   19. The Seven Year –
>   20. Scottish valley
>   22. Black or Dead, for example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Across:

1. Having very bad taste

> Sick

4. English elite school

> Eton

8. Shiraz's country

> Iran

9. Russian car

> Lada

10. Body part or storage device

> Disc

12. "Pas" in faux pas

> Step

13. Mall customer

> Shopper

15. Baseballer Gehrig

> Lou

16. Following as a consequence

> Resulting

21. Diseases, for example

> Ailments

23. A type of golf club

> Iron

24. Frozen beverage

> Icee

25. Actor Ayres and others

> Lews

26. A common last name in Pakistan

> Khan

Down:

1. Accompanying dish

> Side

2. A part of the eye

> Iris

3. Line-walking musician

> Cash

5. London art gallery

> Tate

6. East Germany's border river

> Oder

7. California wine region

> Napa

11. Structural elements that can be Ionic or Doric, for example

> Columns

12. A famous piece of Soviet technology

> Sputnik

14. A European or a piece of track and field equipment

> Pole

16. Train transport

> Rail

17. A country name on euro coins

> Eire

18. How to take it on Kokomo

> Slow

19. The Seven Year –

> Itch

20. Scottish valley

> Glen

22. Black or Dead, for example

> Sea

Comment: EGGcellent + 1 !!!

Comment: +1 in admiration! EGGcelent *2

Comment: All correct except 11 down!

Comment: @jafe Ah, yes. One of two autocorrect typos! Possibly correct now?

Comment: Yeah, all correct. Nice job!

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you work this by printing it out on paper or do you fill it in electronically with a paint program?

Comment: I used Excel, then typed it up on my phone, which was a total pain! Probably took me as long to type than it did to work out the answers.

Answer (score 3):

Partial Answer (combnination of everyone's work with credits)

### Across:

8: Shiraz's country

> IRAN

9: A Russian Car

> LADA (thanks @Ak19!)

12: "Pas" in faux pas

> STEP

15: Baseballer Gehrig

> LOU

### Down:

1: Accompanying dish

> SIDE?

2: A part of the eye

> IRIS?

5: London Art gallery

> TATE (thanks, @Ak19!)

6: East Germany's border river

> ODER

7: California Wine region

> NAPA (thanks, @Ak19!)

Comment: You're welcome+1

Answer (score 3):

Partial

## ACROSS

9: A Russian Car

> Lada?

10: Body part or storage device

> Disk

25. Actor Ayres & others

    > Lews

26: A common last name in Pakistan

> Khan

## DOWN

5: London Art gallery

> Tate

7: California Wine region

> Napa (Thanks OK for confirming)

11. Structural elements that can be Ionic or Doric, for example

    > Capital ?  not sure (JMP found columns)

16: Train Transport

> Rail

19:The seven year -

> Itch

20:Scottish valley

> Lyon

Comment: Nice one @Ak19, +1!

Comment: d7: latter one is the answer

Answer (score 3):

4 across:

> [ETON](https://www.etoncollege.com/)

11 down

> [COLUMNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column#Orders_of_Columns)

22 down

> SEA

Comment: 22D (I was struggling with it!) +1